# SSIS 2008 : crm dynamics 2013 webservice timeout

Tags: web-services, ssis, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using `SSIS 2008` to insert data in `CRM Dynamics 2013`.
We have two servers, the first is for the CRM installation and the seconde SQLServer database.
I wrote a script in SSIS to push data to the CRM, but every time I get a timeout error even if I set it to a higher number.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: `it` to a higher number. Which it are your referring to. Post your code please

Answer (score 0):

Try replicating your script component in to 10 parts. This way, you will have several different instances of service inserting/updating data parallel.